# Removing specific characters from a string in php

Tags: php, char, strpos

How can I check a string in php for specific characters such as '#' or '\'?

I don't really want to use replace, just return true or false.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the function strstr https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php
Returns part of haystack  string from the first occurrence of needle  to the end of haystack

Note: If you only want to determine if a particular needle  occurs within haystack , use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead.

Comment: Cheers it was strpos I was after :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) function, if you only want to know if a string contains another one *(the content of your questions seems to indicate that, even if your title says "remove")*.

Note : don't forget to use the `!==` or `===` operator, as the function can return 0 or false, and those have different meaning.

If you want to "remove" characters, [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/str_replace) or [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) might do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
if (strpos($string, '#') !== false || strpos($string, '\') !== false) {
    // One of those two characters is in the string.
}
```

Note in particular the `!==` syntax, which differentiates between `false` (meaning the character isn't found) and `0` (meaning it was found at position `0`).

Answer (score 0):

Try regular expressions.

```
preg_match('/[#\\\\]/', $String);
```

**Note:** You have to escape backslashes '\' three times.

If you really want them in boolean format, you can use a [ternary operator '?:'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a) as such

```
preg_match('/[#\\\\]/', $String) ? true : false;
```

Or simply convert to boolean

```
(bool)preg_match('/[#\\\\]/', $String);
```