# How to remove first word from string that ends with forwordslash(/) in php

Tags: php, yii2

```
$pathInfo = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
```

This is my code and it will return:

```
/google/agency/create
```

However, I only need `agency/create` as `/google` is dynamic word.

Comment: Can you split the string with '/' and get the array and fetch words using array elements

Comment: try with preg_replace() function in php

Comment: Your question is very general and not clear what you want to achieve. Is this the only result the code will return? If there can be more possibilities please give example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing specific characters from a string in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388966/removing-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-php)

Comment: thanks Deep Kakkar your answer is useful to me...                       $array = spliti("/", $pathInfo, 3);
echo $array[2]; this two lines of code to solve my question.

Comment: Why do you need to parse that URL in the first place? Is this one of your own pages?

Answer (score 2):

You can `explode` the URL string, `unset` the first value and then `implode` it back again.

```
<?php

$url = "/google/agency/create";

$exp = explode("/", trim($url, "/")); // trim the '/' from the URL and explode it
unset($exp[0]); // unset first value
$final_arr = implode("/", $exp); // form the string again

print_r($final_arr);

?>
```

> Output:
>
> agency/create

[Working Example](https://eval.in/531544)

Comment: @RahulPawar, I believe Samir's solution is perfect. It would be of some help if you could accept it. Help those who help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = "/google/agency/create";
$ex = explode('/',$var);
unset($ex[0]); unset($ex[1]);
echo implode("/",$ex);
```

You will get your ans `agency/create`

Answer (score 0):

```
$pathInfo = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']; //   /google/agency/create

$array = spliti("/", $pathInfo, 3); //Array([0] =>[1] => google[2] => agency/create)

echo $array[2]; // required output : agency/create.
```